# How to check insert success or not When i using this code?

Tags: php

How to check insert success or not When i using this code ?

i want to check insert success or not

if success `echo "success";` 
else `echo "error";`

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transaction` (txnid, pro_name, price, status) 
           VALUES (
                    '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
                    '".$data['pro_name']."' ,
                    '".$data['price']."' ,
                    '$status'
                  )", $link);
return mysql_insert_id($link);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
if (!$sql) echo 'error';
else echo 'success';
```

From the docs on [**mysql_query**](https://php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

*For ... INSERT ... mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.*

---

More importantly though, read this: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transaction` (txnid, pro_name, price, status) 
           VALUES (
                    '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
                    '".$data['pro_name']."' ,
                    '".$data['price']."' ,
                    '$status'
                  )", $link);
//------------Changes----------------
$inserted_id = mysql_insert_id($link);
if(mysql_errno() != 0){ 
   echo "error";
else
   echo "success";
return $inserted_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `mysql_insert_id`. it returns new generated id on successful insert.

Check here :

[mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

```
 $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transaction` (txnid, pro_name, price, status) 
           VALUES (
                    '".$data['txn_id']."' ,
                    '".$data['pro_name']."' ,
                    '".$data['price']."' ,
                    '$status'
                  )", $link);

$lastInsertedId = mysql_insert_id($link);

if (empty($lastInsertedId)) 
   $return = 'error';
else 
   $return = $lastInsertedId;

return $return;
```